# Ignoring aggregate error for files without row data in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am running analysis on 300+ csv files and getting the desired output however my R code stops and terminates when it finds a blank csv file in the list without any row data and generates the following error
"Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate".

Basically it is generating the output until it finds a blank csv in list and then terminates the code with this error. I want something in the code which ignores this error because manually checking the blank file would be so inefficient.

The code is very huge however i am reading the files initially using :

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.csv', recursive = TRUE)
```

and then reading several columns from multiple csv files and based on particular columns performing aggregation. Interestingly,in one column i am calculating number of rows from csv files using

```
row <- aggregate(formula=.~day,data=rowdata,FUN=NROW)
```

I doubt if error is generating from this function upon reading blank csv files.

Help needed !

Answer (score 0):

Can you include an `if` condition to check the number of rows in the dataframe?

Something like this :

```
if(nrow(rowdata) > 0) row <- aggregate(.~day,data=rowdata,FUN=NROW)
else NULL
```

Comment: I tried this but error is "argument is of length zero" I also used:  if(!is.null(rowdata) & length(rowdata) > 0 ) however R is retuning same error.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the code that you are using in `for` loop or the apply command? Does using `if(length(rowdata) > 0 && nrow(rowdata) > 0)` help?